# Keep focus on textbox in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Keep focus on textbox in windows phone, I just want SMS app (first party app) behavior.

I have page with textbox and app bar button. When I enter some text and hit the app bar button it looses the textbox focus and keyboard down but in SMS app it is not like that.

How can I keep the focus in textbox ?

Currently, I am trying focus when I hit the button but some flickering is happen right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can set focus on `TextBox` manually using [`Focus()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focus.aspx) method call. It returns `true` or `false` depending on how successful the operation was (focus not always can be set).